# Call Private method in interface

Tags: java, spring

I have following method in the interface implementation which is called by the controller.

```
@Override
public String getCard(Request request, String amount) {
    String card = null;
    List<Card> cards = createCard(request, amount); // THIS IS THE CALL
    card = <API>.getDetails(request, cards);
    return card;
}
```

---

```
private List<Card> createCard(Request request, String amount) {
    List<Card> payment = new ArrayList<>();
        . . . 
    payment.add(card details);
    return payment;
}
```

I neeed to get the list `List<Card> cards` in the controller, but getCard returns card only. Each time, when we call the private method 'createCard', it creates card and store it to the list. Is there any way to get the list without creating card each time?

Comment: Have you tried creating a `getter` method? Is it possible to alter the `createCard()` definition?

Comment: Could you show us the complete class and the interface?

Comment: Your `createCard` method creates new list each time. You can't retrieve information which isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: @NicholasK how can we alter the createCard() definition?

Comment: @Futuregeek: Probably it is best if you share the interface for better results. (I've included an answer, hope it helps)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code on achieving this:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean("cardList")
   @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
   public List<Card> getInstance() {
      return new ArrayList<Card>();
   }
}
```

And whenever you want to use the code simply use

```
    @Service
    class CreateCard{
       @Autowired
       private List<Card> cardList;
       private List<Card> createCard(Request request, String amount) {
       if(!cardList.empty())cardList.clear(); //use this to clear the cardList for previous data

        cardList.add(card details);
        return payment;
        }   

    }
```

This creates `List<Card>` instance once and uses it every time using `@Autowired` by injecting the same instance throughout the application.

Answer (score 1):

You could design your code to have a separate class `Account`. (you can change this name, this was the best I could come up with)

```
class Account {

    private List<Card> cards;

    public Card() {
        this.payment = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // retrieve all cards
    public List<Card> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    // create card and add to list
    void createCard() {
        // alter this as per your requirement
        payment.add("");
    }
}
```

Now using this you have separated 2 functionalities (i.e creation and retrieval) into 2 separate methods `createCard()` and `getCards()` respectively.